# Kendo datepicker date and month values are getting swapped in the .net mvc model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, datepicker

I have added the kendo datepicker in the view (.cshtml) file. When I select the date say '02/03/2017' and submit the form, in .net mvc model the month and date is getting swapped i.e. '03-02-2017 00-00-00'.

Comment: please add relevant code in order to describe your issue

Comment: What's your client side culture / format? My guess is that your client is MM/DD/YYYY which will reach the server as YYYY/MM/DD. If so, this is expected behaviour by the model binder. The client format can vary by culture whilst the server format is always the same.

Comment: Thanks NigelK ..

Comment: @Nigelk, you are correct and I'm sending the date in MM/DD/YYYY format to server side. When the date reaches the .net mvc model the swapping takesplace. Any changes  I have to do in Client/Server side?